# HTTP_USER_AGENT is different than navigator.userAgent

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, user-agent, browser-detection

We use server side detection in PHP (simple) to detect if a device is mobile. This works fine, but sometimes, the server gets the HTTP_USER_AGENT string to be similar to mobile:

> mozilla 5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 7_1_1 like mac x) applewebkit 537.51.2 (khtml, gecko) version 7.0 mobile 11d201 safari 9537.53

The client-side detection (navigator.userAgent), shows a completely different string however:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: maybe you show your `server side detection in PHP`?

Comment: You can change your user-agent in the browser if you know how. A user could be changing it after loading the page before clicking some Ajax element or whatever. Or, you could be misinterpreting what you're looking at. How do you know its the same request?

Comment: And sometimes `user_agent` just lies to you.  You should be using CSS media queries.